# Trigger method in sub component inside slot, $refs not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following template in a specific modal component:

```
<template>
  <my-base-modal ref="BaseModal" :width="1000">
    <template v-slot:header>Details</template>
    <template v-slot:body>
        <detail-card ref="DetailCard"></detail-card>
    </template>
  </my-base-modal>
</template>
```

It creates a base modal and overwrites the slots for header and body.
The body slot is filled with a sub component which needs to load some data.

I tried to use the following method to open and load the content of this modal:

```
open (id) {
   this.$refs.DetailCard.load(id)
   this.$nextTick(() => {
     this.$refs.BaseModal.open()
   })
 }
```

But `this.$refs.DetailCard` is always undefined. I suspect this is because the reference `DetailCard` is defined inside the `body` **slot** of the `<base-modal>` component?

How am I supposed to trigger a function on the `<detail-card>` component in this example, without using EventBus or passing some props into it?

Comment: I would take a wild guess here, that the body of `BaseModal` is not rendered before open is invoked, meaning that its inner DOM elements (including the body slot) is not available at runtime.

Comment: There is a `v-if="isOpen"` around the `BaseModal`. If I change it to `v-show="isOpen"` it works as expected. Thanks! If you write this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that at runtime, the DOM is not rendered until the `BaseModal`'s `open` method is invoked. Therefore, `this.$refs.DetailCard` will returned undefined since the body slot of your component has not rendered with the nested component.

As you have mentioned in the comments, the fix can be as easy as ensuring that the DOM is already rendered, e.g. using `v-show` instead of `v-if`.